# How to make a Voronoi chart with areas proportional to data?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, mesh, charts

In [this chart](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/breaking-down-1-3t-in-nato-defense-spending/) the areas of the voronoi cells have been apportioned so that they represent the fraction of total spending.

[image]

How can I make a chart like this? Suppose we have the data:

```
data = {{"", 860000}, {"", 68080}, {"", 65763}, {"", 56649}, {"",
     31585}, {"", 29105}, {"", 28950}, {"", 19179}, {"", 
    16741}, {"", 15842}, {"", 8814}, {"", 8481}, {"", 7325}, {"",
     7125}, {"", 7076}, {"", 6775}, {"", 5036}, {"", 5033}, {"", 
    4167}, {"", 12400}};
totalSpending = Total[data[[All, 2]]];
```

We'll have `Length[data]` many points, and we'll form a voronoi diagram but clipped inside a circle. The positions of the points need to be optimized such that the cell areas in the (circle) diagram get closer to the fraction of total spending. The first problem to solve would be how to clip the voronoi diagram in a circle.

Comment: I believe this kind of diagram is called a [Voronoi treemap](https://www.amcharts.com/voronoi-treemap/) (in case anyone will look for existing implementations online) :)

Comment: Useful [link](https://graphics.uni-konstanz.de/publikationen/Balzer2005VoronoiTreemaps/index.html) about Voronoi treemaps.

Comment: Clipping could be done like this: vm = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}]];
circle = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Disk[]];
pieces = RegionIntersection[circle, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2];
Show[DeleteCases[pieces, _EmptyRegion]]

Comment: I'm trying to make this work, but unfortunately the following code crashes quite often in (quitting the kernel): `P = RandomPoint[Disk[], 20]; V = VoronoiMesh[P, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]; c = MeshCoordinates[V]; MeshCells[V, 2] /. Polygon[L_] :> RegionIntersection[Region[Polygon[c[[L]]]], Disk[]]`

Comment: @Roman yes I've had a go myself and get similar crashes too. There's some kind of weird bug when calling VoronoiMesh repeatedly, so I might look at a custom voronoi implementation or call out to a library.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer and workaround for the kernel crash problems seen by @Roman in the comments concerning generating a circle masked Voronoi.

I was able to get a Voronoi diagram without using the builtin `VoronoiMesh`. This is a naive implementation *(nearest point for every grid point)* using OpenCL. Getting the cell proportions is then an easy matter of counting the pixel colours.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
source = "
__kernel void voronoi(
__global float2 * points,
__global mint * grid,
__global mint * mask,
mint n, 
mint gridRows,
mint gridColumns,
float realX0,
float realX1,
float realY0,
float realY1)
{
    int gridCol = get_global_id(0);
    int gridRow = get_global_id(1);
    int gridIndex = gridCol + gridRow * gridColumns;

    if(mask[gridIndex] < 1)
    {
        grid[gridIndex] = -1;
        return;
    }

    float xfrac = gridRow / ((float)gridRows);
    float yfrac = gridCol / ((float)gridColumns);
    float2 realPos;
    realPos.x = mix(realX0, realX1, xfrac);
    realPos.y = mix(realY0, realY1, yfrac);

    float mindist = HUGE_VALF;
    int minN = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        float2 p = points[i];
        float d = distance(p,realPos);
        if(d < mindist)
        {
            minN = i;
            mindist = d;
        }
    }
    grid[gridIndex] = minN;
}
";
voronoi = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[source, 
   "voronoi", {{"Float[2]", 1, "Input"}, {_Integer, 1, 
     "Output"}, {_Integer, 1, "Input"}, _Integer, _Integer, _Integer, 
    "Float", "Float", "Float", "Float"}, {16, 16}];
generateVoronoi[points_, gridDim_, mask_] :=
 ArrayReshape[voronoi[
   Flatten[points],
   Flatten@ConstantArray[0, gridDim],
   Flatten@mask,
   Length[points], gridDim[[1]], gridDim[[2]], -1., 1., -1., 1.,
   gridDim
   ], gridDim]

gridDim = {512, 512};
mask = ArrayResample[DiskMatrix[Round[gridDim[[1]]/2]], gridDim, 
   Resampling -> "Nearest"];
maskArea = Total[mask, 2];

n = 20;
points = RandomPoint[Disk[], n];
vor = generateVoronoi[points, gridDim, mask];
vorProportions = 
  N@Values[KeySort[KeyDrop[Counts[Flatten@vor], -1]/maskArea]];
Colorize[vor]
```

[image: Circle masked voronoi diagram]